# Vertical-Align middle stops working after new-line

Tags: html, css

I am using a `max-width` attribute to force a new line. After the new line, the text goes to the bottom of the image instead of remaining in the middle.

CSS:

```
.description{
font:bold 16px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #3D85A7;
margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
text-align:center;
max-width:500px;
}

.icon{
max-height: 90px;
max-width: 85px;
margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="description">
    <img class="icon" src="http://cleanfiles.net/images/pdf.png">
    This is a really really really really long file name.pdf
</div>​
```

For a live example, [view it on a JSFIDDLE here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LXS6x/)

ADDED: Please also notice that my **current** css works well with short file names (the icon moves in and it stays centered). The answers so far have involved `float:`, which does not seem to work well with a shorter filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to change the HTML to (adding `<p>` tag):

```
<div class="description">
  <p>
    <img class="icon" src="http://cleanfiles.net/images/pdf.png">
    This is a really really really really long file name.pdf
  </p>
</div>​
```

And then add the attribute `float: left`to the picture.

**EDIT:**

Here is the link with the text centered (maybe not the best way but it works): http://jsfiddle.net/LXS6x/9/

Comment: The problem with this is that the Icon is too far away with a normal filename: http://jsfiddle.net/LXS6x/10/

Comment: I have set `text-align:left` and a margin-right of 10px on the picture. Let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/LXS6x/20/

Answer (score 0):

You should really wrap the text inside description in order to keep control of the text.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXS6x/3/) example of how you can implement `float` to fix your issue.

**CSS**

```
.description{
  font:bold 16px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #3D85A7;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:500px;
}

.description p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 390px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.icon{
  max-height: 90px;
  max-width: 85px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  float: left;
}​
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As with the other question, the problem with floating is that the Icon is too far away with a normal length filename (try making it shorter). Any thoughts for fixing this?